# Error con un contador

Tags: javascript, html

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo mi código que establece la vida del enemigo, y esta vida baja cada vez que se hace un clic sobre este, también de forma automática por cada objeto que llevo en mi inventario, pero a la hora de disminuir la vida de este enemigo hasta 0 es cuando surge el error, primero el contador llega a 0 y este continua disminuyendo en números negativos y no vuelve a el valor establecido, luego en el contador "gold" aparece un mensaje "undeffined".

```
var enemyHP = 100;
var enemyLife = 100;
var enemyLoot = [100, 300, 200];
var enemyPoint = 100;


function enemyD(){
  enemyHP--;
}

function enemyDAuto(){
  for(life=0; life<inventario.length; life++){
    enemyHP -= inventario[life] * production[life];
  }
}

function enemyChange(){
  if(enemyHP <= 0){
    punto += [simulateEvent(enemyLoot)] + inventario.lenght;
    enemyHP += enemyLife + inventario.lenght;
    enemyLife += 2;

  }
}
```

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h3 id="contador">0</h3> <h3 id="life">0</h3>
      <img src="xxx.png" onclick="clic();"/>
      <img src="Enemies/Zombie.gif" onclick="enemyD();">
      <br><br>
      <button onclick="comprar();" id="Precio">comprar</button>
      <br><br>

      <div id="inventario"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

[image: error]

Comment: Faltan datos, solo pones las funciones, no donde son llamadas, para ayudarte estaría bien que lo incluyeses

Comment: bienvenido, has intentado cosas, lo cual está bien, pero qué se supone que tiene que salir exactamente?

Comment: enemyHP debe volver a su valor base + el numero de items en inventario , lo cual establecí en enemyLife, pero en lugar de eso sigue disminuyendo, eso lo puse arriba con la descripción del problema.

Comment: Por lo que comentas, si el problema es que el contador de la vida baja de 0, en la función enemyD() simplemente agrega un condicional para que si ya es 0 no baje más.

Comment: si, pero si supiera hacerlo ya lo habría hecho eso ya, no se como poner esa condicional.

Comment: La forma más fácil sería que siempre que modifiques `enemyHP` ejecutes después `enemyChange()`, que es donde ya tienes la verificación.

Answer (score 1):

Conseguí hacerlo, y a esta respuesta llegamos a la conclusión junto a un colega.

el código se modifico al siguiente.

```
var enemyHP = 100;
var enemyLife = 100;
var enemyLoot = [100, 300, 200];
var enemyPoint = 100;



function enemyD(){
  enemyHP--;
}

function enemyDAuto(){
    for(life=0; life<inventario.length; life++){
     if(enemyHP > 0){
      enemyHP -= inventario[life] * production[life];
     }
  }
}

function enemyChange(){
  if(enemyHP <= 0){
    punto += 100 + inventario.length;
    enemyHP = enemyLife + inventario.length;
    enemyLife += 2;
  }
}

setInterval(function(){
  enemyChange();
},1000/FPS);
```

Primero que se hizo, se añadió un "If" a la función "enemyAuto" para que parara de ejecutarse cuando llegara a 0 o negativo.

Segundo se introdujo un "setInterval" a la función de "enemyChange" para que ejecutara la función.

Se elimino la función simulateEvent de la operación punto +=, debido a que hacia que el contador relacionado a la variable punto, que es "GOLD", se volviera loco.

La operación de "enemyHP +=" en la función de "enemyChange" se cambio a "enemyHP ="
ya que la función "enemyDAuto" aun puede dar como resultado números negativos debido a que se sumaba con los números negativos igual y el resultado podía ser en un caso de que "enemyHP" este en -5 y sume 105 seria 100 ya que es una suma y no un reemplazo de variable "enemyHP". Se reemplaza la variable, debido a que es un nuevo dígito y cuenta como un reinicio con escalado.